# Como extraer datos de datatable que esta en un modal?

Tags: jquery

Quiero cargar imagenes de una propiedad, pero para lo mismo quiero asociar primero la propiedad en cuestion, entonces abro un modal y muestro un datable con las propiedades y al final un boton asociar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el coidog al tocar cualquier boton de asociar(es uno por registro):

```
        $('#propiedades').on('click', '.e', function (e) {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    
    var data = t.row( row ).data();
    
    
    var id= data.id_propiedad;
    

      });
```

propiedades es el datatable, pero como saco los datos y los cargo en la pagina que contiene el modal y como conservo el id para luego guardar las imagenes?

Comment: requerimos mas explicacion, que deseas hacer, que tienes etc....
una solucion simple seria crear una propiedad data en el elemento `data-asoc="id"` para luego recuperarlo mas adelante..

Comment: Quiero sacar los datos del registro seleccionado y mostrarlo por pantalla al cerrar el modal. Podría usar el localstorage para no perder la info

Comment: "Los datos del registro seleccionado" ¿Es decir, la información de las columnas y mostrarlas en algún alert o algo así?

Comment: Exacto las columnas del registro en el que se presione el botón asociar y mostrarlo por pantalla para que se vea cual es el registro asociado